# a query to show different records

Tags: sql, database, sas

I need to extract data from the table attached below (table has way more columns). I use proc sql in sas eg.

| CODE | COMPONENT | POLICY_STATUS_ID_31_12 | PRODUCT_ID | INVOICE_21_01 | INVOICE_21_02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7456823769020 | DLB | E | C511999 | 34.01 | 18.28 |
| 7456823769020 | DLB | W | C511999 | 43.23 | 27.21 |
| 7456823769030 | FED | E | C611000 | 34.01 | 18.28 |
| 7468237600467 | FED | W | C611001 | 43.23 | 27.21 |
| 7468353769540 | BLB | W | C611001 | 9.08 | 80.12 |
| 7567853745500 | FED | W | C511002 | 3.34 | 92.01 |
| 8546423765600 | TIP | E | C511002 | 78.99 | 78.10 |
| 8546423765600 | TIP | w | C511002 | 78.99 | 78.10 |

I'd need to know the number of codes and the amount of the invoices that have the same product_id but at the same time policy_status_code_31_12 having both W and E. (just look the first 2 rows, they have same code, but different policy_status_id_31_12)
I do this for specific values of a column named component.

I think i should use an having clause but i am not really sure.
i think it in terms of

```
select code, product_id, policy_status_code_31_12, component, sum(invoice_20_01), sum(invoice_20_02)  
from table1 
where component in ('DLB','FED','TIP')
group by code, product_id, policy_status_code_31_12, component 
;
```

Still, i think i am missing smth.... Can someone help me? I want to obtain something like this... a result which shows me those records having same code, same contract_code, same product_id but different policy_status_id_31_12, and consequently values of invoices.

thanks for help

| CODE | COMPONENT | POLICY_STATUS_ID_31_12 | PRODUCT_ID | INVOICE_21_01 | INVOICE_21_02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **7456823769020** | **DLB** | *E* | **C511999** | 34.01 | 18.28 |
| **7456823769020** | **DLB** | *W* | **C511999** | 43.23 | 27.21 |
| **8546423765600** | **TIP** | *E* | **C511002** | 78.99 | 78.10 |
| **8546423765600** | **TIP** | *W* | **C511002** | 78.99 | 78.10 |

Comment: You would normally filter rows with `WHERE`. See: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-where `HAVING` is often used with `GROUP BY` to filter groups based on a specified condition. So, the difference is, are you filtering on groups or on rows? I think you want to filter rows before they end up in a group.

Comment: @kikosoftware you are right, i had to add in the query a filter with a where clause. so you suggest to use having.

Comment: No, I suggest to use `WHERE`.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Please [edit] it. Please show us a sample of the results you want, and please do not use images to show sample data and results. Instread put the text of samples into your question.

Comment: @O.Jones I try to be clearer ... I need to get how many codes have the same product_id and at the same time having values for policy_status_code_31_12 equals to 'E' and 'W' filtered for specific values of a variable "components"

Comment: @O.Jones  I also changed the tables as you suggested

Comment: @Enrico . . . Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: @Enrico . . . I don't get it.  Why isn't C511002 included?  And why is C511999 included when ZRA is filtered out?

Comment: @GordonLinoff you're right. I corrected the values in the tables. The final table shows the results i'd like to get (all those records having same code, component, product_id but different policy_status_code_31_12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your question's data in a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kaucwJw7wAjWBpSFTpTpxU/4).

I added some rows to the table because I'm not completely clear about your requirement. The the first extra row contains 'N' where the other rows contain 'E' or 'W'. The second adds a 'W' row matching another  'E' row. The last row adds another 'E' record to one that has both 'E' and 'W'

```
7456823769020    DLB    N    C511999    12.34    43.21
7456823769030    FED    W    C611000    34.56    98.76
8546423765600    TIP    E    C511002    98.77    65.43
```

This query summarizes your table entries, but does nothing to filter by 'E' and 'W'

```sql
    select code, product_id, 
           group_concat(policy_status_id_31_12 
                        ORDER BY policy_status_id_31_12) statuses, 
           component, 
           sum(invoice_21_01) sum1, sum(invoice_21_02) sum2  
    from table1 
    where component in ('DLB','FED','TIP')
    group by code, product_id, component;
```

It produces this result set.

| code | product_id | component | statuses | sum1 | sum2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7456823769020 | C511999 | DLB | E,N,W | 89.58 | 88.70 |
| 7456823769030 | C611000 | FED | E,W | 68.57 | 117.04 |
| 7468237600467 | C611001 | FED | W | 43.23 | 27.21 |
| 7567853745500 | C511002 | FED | W | 3.34 | 92.01 |
| 8546423765600 | C511002 | TIP | E,E,W | 256.75 | 221.63 |

Now, it is clear from your question that you want the second of these rows in your filtered result set: it has both 'E' and 'W' status. And it's clear you do not want the the third and fourth rows.

But I cannot tell from your question what you want to do about the first and last rows.

If you want to simply ingore the 'N' status and take rows with one each of 'E' and 'W' you can do this. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kaucwJw7wAjWBpSFTpTpxU/5)

```
select code, product_id, 
       group_concat(policy_status_id_31_12 
                    ORDER BY policy_status_id_31_12) statuses, 
       component, 
       sum(invoice_21_01) sum1, sum(invoice_21_02) sum2  
from table1 
where component in ('DLB','FED','TIP')
  and policy_status_id_31_12 IN ('E', 'W')
group by code, product_id, component 
having COUNT(*) = 2
```

If you want to filter by rows containing *exactly one each* of 'E' and 'W' but still incude the 'N' in your sums you can do this. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kaucwJw7wAjWBpSFTpTpxU/6)

```
select code, product_id, 
       group_concat(policy_status_id_31_12 
                    ORDER BY policy_status_id_31_12) statuses, 
       component, 
       sum(invoice_21_01) sum1, sum(invoice_21_02) sum2  
from table1 
where component in ('DLB','FED','TIP')
group by code, product_id, component 
having SUM(policy_status_id_31_12 = 'E') = 1
   and SUM(policy_status_id_31_12 = 'W') = 1
```

If you want to filter by rows containing *at least one each* of 'E' and 'W' but no other rows you can do this (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kaucwJw7wAjWBpSFTpTpxU/8)

```
select code, product_id, 
       group_concat(policy_status_id_31_12 
                    ORDER BY policy_status_id_31_12) statuses, 
       component, 
       sum(invoice_21_01) sum1, sum(invoice_21_02) sum2  
from table1 
where component in ('DLB','FED','TIP')
group by code, product_id, component 
having SUM(policy_status_id_31_12 = 'E') >= 1
   and SUM(policy_status_id_31_12 = 'W') >= 1
   and SUM(policy_status_id_31_12 NOT IN('E', 'W')) = 0
```

The `HAVING SUM()` pattern can help you get this right.

Answer (score 0):

Having Clause is only used for Aggregation like `HAVING SUM(col)>0`. you can use `WHERE` Clause.

Updated the answer after the change in the question

```
SELECT code,product_id, policy_status_code_31_12, SUM(invoice_20_01), SUM(invoice_20_02)  
FROM table1 
WHERE component IN ('DLB','FED','TIP') AND policy_status_code_31_12 IN ('W','E')
GROUP BY code,product_id,policy_status_code_31_12
```